# How to export a class under a module in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, class, module

I'm trying to export a class named Car in JavaScript and import it into another JavaScript file. Both JavaScript files are running live on a console under an html file. (So this may possibly be an html code problem).

I did the export keyword for the file being exported. 
I did the import keyword for the file receiving the export. 
After this is done, I check my live console running HTML (my Javascript files are linked with the HTML file). And I get a SyntaxError.

```
//script.js 

import { Car } from "./models/car.js";

let car = new Car(123);
console.log( car.id );

    //car.js
    export class Car {
    constructor(id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

And here's an imgur LINK to the html file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bM5w9.jpg

I expect the console in the live html webpage to log out "123".
Instead I got `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`
I've already tried taking out the curly braces, but then  I just get another error.

Comment: `import` is an ES6 feature that isn't supported by browsers yet.

Comment: That's interesting.. the tutorial guide didn't go over that, there should be a way to get the "123" logged in the console though, no?

Comment: The html file is only being used for the console feature, and it links the `car.js`, and `script.js` files.